# How to interpolate integer rasters to floating point?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, integration, floating-point

I have an reclassified raster, I need to convert it to floating point, the "float" tool does not suffice, because I need the output values to be spatially interpolated. For example, at the midpoint of zone 2 (halfway between borders of zone 1 and zone 3) I need the values to be 2.5, using the float tool these values would simply be 2.0

I am using ArcGIS 10.2

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, what you want is smooth boundaries. Therefore you should use [focal statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000qs000000.htm) with the MEAN value and  a small (3*3) window. Low pass filter could also help.

As a remark, this function will not "add" pixels between each class. It will create a gradient of 3 3 3 2.66 2.33 2 2 2 from 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2. If you want a value **between** your pixel, 3 3 2 2 -> 3 **3** 3 **2.5** 2  **2** 2 then you need to resample with a reduced pixel size (using bilinear interpolation)